# python mock verify the parameter of a sub function call

Tags: python, mocking

```
def doublen(n):
    n = fun(n)
    return 2*n

def fun(n):
    return n+1

def test_wy(self):
   client = mock.Mock()
   client.double(1)
   client.double.assert_called_with(1)
   client.double.fun.assert_called_with(1)
```

The second assert `client.double.fun.assert_called_with(1)` throws an error, is there any errors of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Mock is just used to mock different object in your system (create dummy objects). It is not what you are thinking.

if you want to see no error for 
client.double.fun.assert_called_with(1)

then you should have a call client.double.fun(1) before.

Comment: client.double(1) will not call client.double.fun(1)?if so, how can I verify whether function `fun(1)` has been called when function `double(1)` is executed?

Comment: nope it does not call it will this is just a mock don't confuse with unit testing. You should use pyTest if you wanted to do unittest of your functions.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def rm(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
from mymodule import rm
 
import mock
import unittest
 
class RmTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
 
    @mock.patch('mymodule.os')
    def test_rm(self, mock_os):
        rm("any path")
        # test that rm called os.remove with the right parameters
        mock_os.remove.assert_called_with("any path")` but this is ok

Comment: here you are mocking os. so mock_os.remove.assert_called_with("any path") works. lets assume remove calls one more method then you cant check that here something like mock_os.remove.another_method.assert_called_with("any path").